# Custom Invoice ID

Tags: invoice

My customer wants a different Invoice ID numbering.

A sequence based on year and contribution type.

So, something like 
Event-2015-001
Event-2015-002
..
Event-2015-156
Event-2016-001
Memb-2015-001
Memb-2015-002
..
Memb-2015-129
Memb-2016-001

How would you approach that? 
What are the (unwanted) side-effects?

The invoices are generated by CiviCRM (so not an external source of the Invoice ID). The invoice ID's will be used by a financial package.

---

Thanks for the answers.
After I showed the customer that Invoice ID's were adjustable with Batch Update Contributions via Profile they want to use that for now. Maybe later we will automate it.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the overall process? What are you doing that originates the invoice? This will help others to understand your problem and the answer you will get :-)

Comment: Adjusted the question a bit

Comment: What are the unwanted side-effects? The invoice-id is used by payment processors for different tasks: See https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20387

Comment: I won't pretend to understand Civi's invoicing system - but I saw something that seems relevant in my Github feed, where the human-readable invoice ID is going to be a separate field from the internal invoice ID.  I believe that this will make what you're describing possible, or at least get you most of the way there: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10298

Comment: probably useful to add your own answer as an Answer and +1 it

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is in the making: Klaas and Björn just proposed this PR: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11110

Comment: Yes, the new hook proposed in [CRM-21289](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21289) would exactly cover this scenario. Just waiting for it to be accepted... Björn.

Comment: I gave it my thumbs up 

Comment: Any news on this? My client wants to use invoices, but wants to use their own invoice numbering system.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is the invoiceID generated? I am not aware of any invoiceID generated automatically but that may well be my bad :-)
If there is an invoice generated I would imagine you would be able to use the hook_civicrm_pre or if not the hook_civicrm_post on the Entity **ParticipantPayment** to catch and change the invoice ID?

Comment: Invoicing was added in CiviCRM 4.6 - https://civicrm.org/blogs/tonymazz/civicrm-46-will-support-sales-tax-vat-and-invoicing

Comment: Thanks William :-) Hans, did you try with the civicrm_pre hook?

Comment: Hoi Erik! invoice_id generation was added by Lobo a decade ago :-) It has been sent to payment processors - just about any of them for what must amount to millions of transactions; the 4.6 invoicing feature accidentally repurposed that field - that's now being separated out by Coleman.

Comment: Hoi Karin, I know about the invoice_id by now :-). One of the problems we are facing is that most of our customers want their own numbering system, and the 4.6 invoice id generation does not call any hook unfortunately! But moving house right now......:-)

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer but hope gives some insights.

The invoice ID is taken from the contribution ID, that said, I would rather go for a custom filed/extension. I do remember that contribution ID AND invoice ID (when applicable) is used to check against existing contributions, not 100% sure about this but perhaps someone from the core team could clarify.

There was a similar question [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/7578/872)