# Invoices option

Tags: invoice

I have a question, please?
in case validated creation invoice option on CiviCRM, is there any possibility to use it for the events only, and deactivate it for the membership?
Thanks,

Comment: Can you please provide more details on what you want to achieve?

Comment: I am not an expert in CiviCRM, we have 2 types of activities in which we are thinking of activating the option of creating the invoices through CIVI, these activities are ( membership fee and Event's registration fee, so the reference of the invoices shouldn't be the same), ex the event's invoices ref should start with EVE/YEAR/*** and the membership fee should start with REN/YEAR/**** OR NEW/YEAR/****? is this available in CEVI?????

Answer (score 2):

To me it sounds as if there has been a similar question with some answers some years ago in this forum:

[Custom Invoice ID](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8391/custom-invoice-id)

The latest comments are from 2017/2018. Apparently, there has been a PR for custom invoice IDs, but it appears to be closed without pulling it into core.

However, some workarounds are discussed also. Hope this helps a bit.